# Angularjs 1.2.6 and 1.2.14 showing 1.2.5 error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I got this error message while i'm using angular 1.2.6 and tried 1.2.14 but the error message still showing.

```
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…
 F1.2.5%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20
 (native...<omitted>...5) `
```

I already check my dependencies, I think there got nothing wrong.

The weird thing is my web app still running well with this error.

Comment: Hey, could you just give some comment before you downvote?

Comment: do u manage to fix it? I'm getting the exact same error when I migrated from 1.0.5 to 1.2.14 Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/modulerr

Comment: @MuhammadZubair  no, i thought it is only me until you comment to this. I check back my another web app. This error suddenly come out as well

Comment: @MuhammadZubair  check my answer, may help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT.

It is error from chrome extension which written by angularjs !!!

Not my app error.

^#$%#@#$^&$%^@&$%&$#^&$%^